# Where to check my paper grammars for free of charge?

Tags: grammar

Where to check my paper grammars for free of charge?
Do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some universities have writing services that can be free (for instance, are free for PhD students). While they might not want to check all your paper's grammar, they will definitely give you resources to improve your writing and grammar.

Answer (score 6):

Unless they are your friends in real life, it's very unlikely anyone will help you check your grammar for free. It takes time and effort, and could easily take several hours especially if the reader is also going for comprehension. There's a reason why professional proofreading services are not cheap.

If you're not willing/able to pay for this kind of service, then the best you can do is use a free grammar checking program such as [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/). It'll not be nearly as good as a human proofreader, but it's better than nothing.